# How to get a javascript alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, alert

I'm definitely not a newbie to scripting, but this just boggles my mind. I want to invoke a function on a button click, so I first wanted to grab the buttonclick event and test that with a simple window.alert. So I just wrote the html document below.

```
<!doctype html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#sendButton").click(function(){
                    alert("clicked!!");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form id="send-message-area">
            <input type="button" id="sendButton" value="Send Message">
        </form>
    </body>
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens. At all. Since this is fairly simple code, I have no clue why this wouldn't work.

Comment: What happens if you put your alert outside the click? I want to know if doc.ready() isn't being called or the click

Comment: It works.... http://jsfiddle.net/HbUs3/

Comment: Check your console for error and then improve your question by posting error message if any...

Comment: Are you viewing your file locally?

Comment: I think @Murli is correct and you should change your `jquery  version` for `IE`

Comment: If you use chrome to develop you can use view->developer->developer tools to see the actual error. Developer tools can help you debug javascript.

Comment: @jeremy, or just F12 - works in all the major browsers.

Comment: @davidkonrad nice tip for me it doesn't work on mac.

Comment: OK, in works in all major browsers _except_ if you are using mac :)

Comment: Think this is a close-candidate. We can continue guessing out of the blue, but obviosuly this is caused by some local wrong setup, error in other code than the shown, a firewall preventing using the CDN or 1000 other things - it *should* work and it is impossible to guess why it does not on kramer65's localhost.

Comment: @davidkonrad Ya, and OP still didn't answer simple questions as which browser he's testing it? Is it local file without server? Any error in console? Etc, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script tag to pull in jQuery is using the [`(Common|General) Internet Syntax Scheme`](http://sharovatov.wordpress.com/2009/04/17/common-internet-scheme-syntax-detailed-post/). This tells the browser to use whatever scheme was used to load the page in loading the script. It is helpful for sites which respond to both http and https.

If you are viewing your file locally using the `file://` scheme, then you should see an error that $ is not defined. This is because the script does not live at:

```
file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
```

Please use this src in the script tag when loading locally:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: any reason for that? Chrome local file?!

Comment: Unless the OP is viewing a file on his local machine using the `file://` scheme. Then there will be problems.

Comment: Essentially if the html file is loaded by double clicking, the // URL won't resolve, one need to use http

Comment: This was indeed it. Stupid how such a simple thing can mess me up! Excuse me for all you guys time, but you've saved me another couple hours of banging my head against the wall!

Answer (score 2):

According to your url starting with `//` the browser tries to load that file from your local file system if you're locally testing your site using an url like `file://`. In that case you're not loading jQuery, so the `$` is undefined and your code never executed.

Use the `script` tag like that for local tests:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you run your site on a web server, the cdn-style starting with `//` will work again.

Answer (score 2):

Path to src should be complete if you have hosted it somewhere.You have not added correct path to jquery library. Everything will work accordingly once you do that.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HbUs3/)**

Comment: @A.Wolff:dont you think missing http will try loading the library if it is hosted somewhere.

Comment: Using `http:` is not a good idea, because protocal for CDN is not known beforehand

Comment: The only problem if not using http or https to specify protocol is if html page is used locally in chrome without using server, file protocol is assumed

Comment: not sure about it. In asp.net if http is missing, it looks for file in project directory even  if it is hosted somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Code looks fine

I think you are testing in IE < 9 (jQuery 2.x not supporting IE 8)

Please change the browser or load jQuery version like 1.9 and test it

Answer (score 0):

You have to update query script src to 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js'

I recommend to download the jQuery script then add it to your project locally instead of the remote one

Comment: `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js` is fine as long you don't view it on your local machine, it's just a protocol independent link.

Answer (score 0):

use  `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js">` and practise to insert `html` tag

**HTML**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#sendButton").click(function(){
                    alert("clicked!!");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form id="send-message-area">
        <input type="button" id="sendButton" value="Send Message">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to include `http:/` in your `script` `src`.

Either change your script tag like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or download the `Jquery` file and refer locally.

Answer (score 0):

Change your path to

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and try to use jquery 1.10 for less than ie9 browser

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><!--><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script><!--<![endif]-->
```